# C++ : Best practice when implementing Multiple inheritance

Tags: c++, qt, templates, multiple-inheritance, virtual-inheritance

I have to add multiples of two types of Graphics Items (`QGraphicsRectItem` and `QGraphicsEllipseItem`) to a `QGraphicsScene` (which is added to `QGraphicsView`). Each graphics item should be able to interact with the mouse and keyboard events. So initially I designed the classes as below.

#### Initial design:

```
class myQGraphicsRectItem : public QGraphicsRectItem
{
public:
    explicit myQGraphicsRectItem();
private:
    void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event);
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event);
    void focusOutEvent(QFocusEvent *event);
    //Many events goes here
    void fnCreateRect();
};

class myQGraphicsRectItem : public QGraphicsEllipseItem
{
public:
    explicit myQGraphicsRectItem();
private:
    void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event);
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event);
    void focusOutEvent(QFocusEvent *event);
    //Many events goes here
   void fnCreateCircle();
};
```

To know how to avoid duplicate event declaration and definition, I read the answers to:

- [Multiple Inheritance Ambiguous Call](/q/18158094)
- [Templates only be implemented in the header file?](/q/495021)
- [Virtual base class](/q/21558)

and finally designed the class as below     .

### Modified design:

#### header file

```
template <class T>
class myQGraphicsRectItem : public QGraphicsRectItem , public QGraphicsEllipseItem{
     /*commented the below event methods in the base classes*/
     void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event);
     void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event);
     void focusOutEvent(QFocusEvent *event);
     //Many events goes here
}
```

#### implementation file

```
template <class T> myGraphicsItem<T>::myGraphicsItem()
{
    this->T::setFlags(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable|QGraphicsItem::ItemIsFocusable);
    this->T::setFocus();
}     

//**All event function definition goes here....**     

template <class T> QGraphicsItem *myGraphicsItem<T>::fnGetRectObject()
{
    fnCreateRect();
    return (T*)this;
}
```

#### calling code

```
#include "mygraphicsitem.h"
#include "mygraphicsitem.cpp"

void MainWindow::on_PushButton_clicked()
{
    myGraphicsItem<myQGraphicsRectItem> *rr = new myGraphicsItem<myQGraphicsRectItem>();
    scene->addItem(rr->fnGetRectObject());
}
```

And the application is working as expected with this modified design. But I have some doubts with this design, as follows:

1. Is this a best practice to handle this scenario or should I go with the initial method? or any other best method is there (to write single code to handle events)?
2. Both the `QGraphicsRectItem` and `QGraphicsEllipseItem` inherit from `QAbstractGraphicsShapeItem`. So do I need to handle the virtual base class concept?

Comment: I think this should be on [CR](codereview.stackexchange.com). Please note that cross-posting isn't considered as "good behaviour".

Comment: You can simply let myQGraphicsRectItem inherit from T alone, and thus remove the multiple inheritance.

Comment: @Jonathan, Trying the concept what you have said....

Comment: Keep in mind that this code works fine since none of the `*GraphicsItem`'s inherit `QObject`. Multiple inheritance from `QObject` doesn't work.

Comment: @Jonathan. Its working fine. i am satisfied with this method.

Comment: @iksemyonov. Thanks for sharing your knowledge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wow, that's over thinking the solution to the problem!

> any other best method is there (to write single code to handle events)?

For me, the question is not clear in what you're trying to achieve, possibly due to the attempted solution, so I'm going to assume that with the two classes, `QGraphicsRectItem` and `QGraphicsEllipseItem`, you're trying to have a single block of code to handle custom events, such as mouse, keys etc.

In this case, Qt provides you with all you need in the call to [installSceneEventFilter](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#installSceneEventFilter).

Simply create a class that's derived from `QGraphicsItem` and reimplement the events you want to handle. Then add this new class to the other instances with `installSceneEventFilter`

```
class QGraphicsItemEventsFilter : public QGraphicsItem
{
    private:
        void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event);
        void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event);
        void focusOutEvent(QFocusEvent *event);
};
```

Instantiate the filter and add it to the other classes

```
QGraphicsItemEventsFilter* pFilter = new QGraphicsItemEventsFilter;

QGraphicsRectItem* pRect = new QGraphicsRectItem;
pRect->installSceneEventFilter(pFilter);

QGraphicsEllipseItem* pEllipse = new QGraphicsEllipseItem;
pEllipse->installSceneEventFilter(pFilter);
```

Now all events for both `pRect` and `pEllipse` will be handled by the event filter, pFilter.

Comment: After seeing your answer, yes really it is (my methods) over thinking :)  . I need to learn more on QT. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

A general answer (without reading through your code in detail) from my experience with Qt is: If you think you must use multiple inheritance do deal with Qt classes and subclasses, you most probably are doing it wrong - which in turn is most probably a sign that you didn't understand the mechanism completely. Qt is quite well designed, and if you do things as intended you don't need multiple inheritance.

Try to think about it again, and go looking for examples of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your knowledge. I tried Jonathan comment, and avoided the multiple inheritance.

Comment: Whilst useful information, this doesn't attempt to answer the question and would have been better posted as a comment.

Comment: @TheDarkKnight if it is giving the OP a tool to do what they want to do better and with less pain, I fail to see how it is not an answer (that doesn't mean yours isn't certainly more verbose and specific)

Comment: @Gimby bad choice of words - a method, a course change

Comment: @Gimby maybe - but it's still silly to try and get it removed by moderators for not being an answer. If you don't like it, just downvote it.